# How to fit a line to loglog data using curvefit in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, line, curve-fitting

I have a loglog plot which I need to find the gradient of the line of best fit. I've tried using python's curvefit function to find the gradient but the line of best fit clearly isn't fitted correctly. Is there anything I need to change in my code below?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[7,7])
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.errorbar(m, unumpy.nominal_values(dn_dm) , yerr= unumpy.std_devs(dn_dm), fmt='k.', label='Data')

newX = np.logspace(-.25, .5, base=10)

def myExpFunc(x, a, b):
    return a * np.power(x, b)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(myExpFunc, m, unumpy.nominal_values(dn_dm))
ax.plot(newX, myExpFunc(newX, *popt), 'r-')
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps, because you're doing a log/log plot of your data, the fit is actually good, but the log/log representation of it is making it appear that it's not.  As an alternative, you could try doing a _linear_ fit to the log() of your data values.  ie `m_log = np.log(m)` and `vals_log = np.log(unumpy.nominal_values())`

Comment: ...are you considering the error bars in your fit? You also might want to do so.

Comment: @Lewis Cooper. Instead of a graph better joint the numerical data to your question ( or at least a smaller representative data example) so that one could reproduce what you observed.

Comment: Probably the criteria of fitting implemented in your software is Least Mean Square Error which gives a good graphical representation in lin/lin. If you want a better graphical representation in log/log change the criteria of fitting which should be Least Mean Square Relative Error.